# what is the relation between Green function G(x,t), G*(x,t) and G*(t,x) for second order Linear differential operator L[y]=y''.

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

As I know by Theorem If G(x,t) is Green’s function for the linear operator L and G*(x, t) is Green’s function for its adjoint operator L*, then G(x,t) =
G*(t, x).
Is this also true that two functions are related by G*(x,t) = −G(x,t); if L is self-adjoint. I review a research paper who claim this result for Linear operator L[y]=y''(x).
Can someone tell me the relation and what will be the G*(x,t)?

Comment: So, this theorem says that if $G(x,t)$ is the Green's function of $L$, then $G^\ast(x,t)=G(t,x)$ is the Green's function of the adjoint $L^\ast$. That means if $L$ is self-adjoint, then $L^\ast=L$ and therefore $G(t,x)=G^\ast(x,t)=G(x,t)$. And if $L$ is skew-adjoint, then $L^\ast=-L$, which means $G(t,x)=G^\ast(x,t)=-G(x,t)$. Right?

Comment: but our operator is self adjoint  i.e. L=L* for L[y]=y''. Green fuction is given by  x(t −1) when  0 < x < t and  t(x − 1) when t < x < 1.  
.

Comment: So? The theorem says $G^\ast(x,t)=G(t,x)$ for *any* operator $L$, whether it's self-adjoint or not. So it's *always* true that $G^\ast(x,t)=G(t,x)$. However, in the case $L^\ast=L$, we can say that $L$ and $L^\ast$ must have the same Green's function, so $G^\ast(x,t)=G(x,t)$. On the other hand, in the case that $L^\ast=-L$, if we write out the differential equation defining $G$ and multiply by $-1$, then replace $-L$ with $L^\ast$, we find that $-G(x,t)$ is the Green's function of $L^\ast$, i.e. $G^\ast(x,t)=-G(x,t)$ in that case.

Comment: In summary, we can conclude $G(x,t)=G(t,x)$ for self-adjoint $L$ and $G(x,t)=-G(t,x)$ for skew-adjoint $L$.